# Jquery each loop showing first value as zero or NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to gather data from a dynamically created table via Jquery. I am able to get the data, but now I want to sum up the fields and put the result inside a text field or label etc dynamically when I press enter. I am using the following code:

```
$("#iq").keypress(function(e)
{
   if(e.which==13)
     {
       var tot=0;
       $('#tab .itemtotal').each(function()
       {
         tot = tot + parseInt($(this).html());
       });
       $("#totalamount").val(tot);
     }
 });
```

My problem is that the value showing in the textfield is zero or NaN for the first time and after that its calculating correctly. I used the same code and associating it with a button and checking its click event and its working properly and showing first item also.

Any suggestions? If need some more clarification let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So there's an issue with the values you're calculating? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle link for your problem?

Comment: Yes its skipping the first value of the table.

Comment: Don't add a "fiddle link" until you've added all relevant information to the question itself.

Comment: `parseInt($(this).html())` returns `NaN` in one or more of the iterations, and `NaN + anything` is still `NaN` !

Comment: Its a big project and this code is making issue so no fiddle code. But if not solved i will trim the code and make the fiddle code.

Comment: What you need to do is create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The code you gave will work perfectly if everything else is perfect. If something else is wrong, we can't possibly know what it is without seeing it.

Comment: You should debug using `console.log()`, as in `console.log($(this).html(), parseInt($(this).html()));`